# .htaccess redirect image Path to php file

Tags: php, image, .htaccess, jpeg

I am trying to show an image generated by PHP code, retrieved from db by calling a specific url "protoselido.jpg". What i want is to call domain.com/protoselido.jpg and show the feedFrontpage.php result.
Currently returns 404 Not Found, i have tried many versions.
*I am running Nginx before apache

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
RewriteBasse /

RewriteRule ^protoselido\.jpg$ feedFrontpage.php [L]
```

Comment: And "does not work" means what _exactly_? Do you get a wrong result? Do you get an error? does nothing happen at all? Do you get a white page? Does the universe implode? _Be precise..._

Comment: I need others to fetch .jpg files so the extension .jpg MUST be there. If i remove it it works, but it won't work for me..

Comment: I get 404 Not Found

Comment: The pattern should be `^protoselido\.jpg$`, but that is not the issue here. Just sayin...

Comment: I want https://www.imerisia-ver.gr/protoselido/image that returns the image now, to be /protoselido/image.jpg

Comment: That clearly contradicts what you wrote before.

Comment: tried that too.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/150195/discussion-between-arkascha-and-decodernt).

Comment: u talking about the url paths? i am working on it right now and make changes..